# Need to create different class depending on type in Generic class

Tags: java

I am using a tool which is generating differrenct classes for different structs I am using

For example it may create two class like this

```
  class TypeSupportImpl {
      void callme()
      {
          System.out.println("I an here");
      }

      void test()
      {

      }
  }

 public class StringReader extends  TypeSupportImpl
 {
     void callme()
     {
         System.out.println("HelloReader an here");
     }

     void test()
     {

     }

     public static String get_name() {
         String s = "hello"; 
         return s ;
     }
 }

public class HelloReader extends  TypeSupportImpl
{
    void callme()
    {
        System.out.println("HelloReader an here");
    }

    void test()
    {

    }

    public static String get_name() {
        String s = "hello"; 
        return s ;
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a generic wrapper for this class. I want to generic wrapper to behave in such a way that, if user passes `Hello` as the type it should create object of `Helloreader`. If the users basses in a `String` then a `StringReader` object should be created.

```
public class TestCode<T > {
    //if T= Hello
    HelloReader.get_name();
    //if T== String
    StringReader.get_name()
}
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve it best way without using reflection.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. `static` method do not even work with generics. Why is it not an instance method and already defined in `TypeSupportImpl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it at all, even with reflection. Type erasure means that at runtime, you won't be able to see what the type parameter is, and even if you pass it in as an argument (see the builders for `EnumSet`), you'd have to use reflection, since `static` elements are bound to a specific type at compile-time.